Issue with connecting to a server using Apache sshd Java
I was trying to connect to a remote server(node1) tunneling through a different remote server(gateway). I was able to connect to to gateway server. But, I'm unable to establish connection with node1 through tunneling. May be I'm missing something which I'm not able to understand.
package org.example;

import org.apache.sshd.client.ClientBuilder;
import org.apache.sshd.client.SshClient;
import org.apache.sshd.client.channel.ChannelExec;
import org.apache.sshd.client.channel.ClientChannelEvent;
import org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSession;
import org.apache.sshd.common.NamedFactory;
import org.apache.sshd.common.compression.BuiltinCompressions;
import org.apache.sshd.common.config.keys.FilePasswordProvider;
import org.apache.sshd.common.kex.KeyExchangeFactory;
import org.apache.sshd.common.keyprovider.FileKeyPairProvider;
import org.apache.sshd.common.keyprovider.KeyPairProvider;
import org.apache.sshd.common.util.net.SshdSocketAddress;
import org.apache.sshd.common.kex.BuiltinDHFactories;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class RemoteCommandExecutor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String gatewayHost = "host ip";
        String gatewayUser = "username";
        String gatewayPassword = "passeord";
        int localPort = 12345; // Choose any unused port
        int remotePort = 22; // SSH port on node1

        String node1Host = "ixxxxxx017";
        String node1User = "username";
        String passphrase = "password";
        List<String> commands = List.of("hostname", "cd /home/", "ls -lrt");

        String privateKeyPath = "/home/"+gatewayUser+"/.ssh/id_rsa";

        try {
            SshClient client = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient();
            client.setCompressionFactoriesNames(BuiltinCompressions.Constants.NONE);
            client.setCipherFactoriesNames("aes256-gcm@openssh.com","aes128-gcm@openssh.com","aes256-ctr","aes192-ctr","aes128-ctr");
            client.setMacFactoriesNames("hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com","hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com","hmac-sha2-256","hmac-sha2-512");
            List<KeyExchangeFactory> keyExchangeFactories = new ArrayList<KeyExchangeFactory>();


            keyExchangeFactories.addAll(NamedFactory.setUpTransformedFactories(
                    false,
                    List.of(BuiltinDHFactories.curve25519),
                    ClientBuilder.DH2KEX));

            // Update the key exchange factories
            client.setKeyExchangeFactories(keyExchangeFactories);
            List<KeyExchangeFactory> currentList = client.getKeyExchangeFactories();
            //print currentList
            for(KeyExchangeFactory f : currentList) {
                System.out.println("ascdsfdff  ---  \n"+f.toString());
            }

            // Start the client (if not already started
            client.start();
            // Connect to Gateway with Password Authentication
            try (ClientSession gatewaySession = client.connect(gatewayUser, gatewayHost, 22)
                    .verify().getSession()) {
                gatewaySession.addPasswordIdentity(gatewayPassword);
                gatewaySession.auth().verify();
                String testOutput = executeCommand(gatewaySession, "ls -l");
                System.out.println("Testing" + testOutput);
                // Establish tunnel (if needed)
                gatewaySession.startLocalPortForwarding(
                        new SshdSocketAddress("localhost", localPort), // Local address and port
                        new SshdSocketAddress(node1Host, remotePort) // Remote address and port
                );

                for(KeyExchangeFactory f : client.getKeyExchangeFactories()) {
                    System.out.println("ascdsfdff  ---  \n"+f.toString());
                }

                // Connect to node1 with Password Authentication (through tunnel)
                // Connect to node1 with Private Key Authentication (through tunnel)
                try (ClientSession node1Session = client.connect(node1User, "localhost", localPort)
                        .verify().getSession()) {
                    // Fetch the private key contents from the gateway server
                    String privateKeyContents = executeCommand(gatewaySession, "cat " + privateKeyPath);

                    // Create a temporary file to store the private key contents
                    File tempPrivateKeyFile = File.createTempFile("temp-private-key", ".pem");
                    Files.write(tempPrivateKeyFile.toPath(), privateKeyContents.getBytes());

                    // Use the temporary file to load the private key
                    KeyPairProvider keyPairProvider = new FileKeyPairProvider(List.of(tempPrivateKeyFile.toPath()));
                    ((FileKeyPairProvider) keyPairProvider).setPasswordFinder(FilePasswordProvider.of(passphrase));

                    // Load the key pair
                    Iterable<KeyPair> keyPairs = keyPairProvider.loadKeys(node1Session);

                    // Get the first key pair
                    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairs.iterator().next();

                    // Add the public key identity from the loaded key pair
                    node1Session.addPublicKeyIdentity(keyPair);

                    node1Session.auth().verify();
                    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (String cmd : commands) {
                        String output = executeCommand(node1Session, cmd);
                        results.add(output);
                    }

                    // Combine and print results
                    String combinedOutput = results.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n---\n"));
                    System.out.println(combinedOutput);
                }
            } finally {
                client.stop();
                client.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static String executeCommand(ClientSession session, String command) throws Exception {
        ChannelExec channelExec = session.createExecChannel(command);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream err = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        channelExec.setOut(out);
        channelExec.setErr(err);
        channelExec.open();
        channelExec.waitFor(EnumSet.of(ClientChannelEvent.CLOSED), 0);

        String output = new String(out.toByteArray());
        String error = new String(err.toByteArray());

        if (!error.isEmpty() && !error.contains("cannot find name for group ID")) {
            throw new Exception("Command execution error: " + error);
        }
        return output;
    }
}


It is able to connect to gatewayHost. But, not able to establish connection with node1Host. I see the following error.
Error: Unable to negotiate key exchange for server host key algorithms (client: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa / server: ssh-ed25519)

These are the maven dependencies I'm using.
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
            <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version> </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
            <artifactId>sshd-sftp</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
            <artifactId>sshd-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


I've tried setting different KeyExchangeFactories and it doesn't help

Does this answer your question? java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to negotiate key exchange for server host key algorithms

Added BouncyCastleProvider as Security provider and set Signature Factories to fix this issue

            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            client.setSignatureFactories(Arrays.asList(
                    BuiltinSignatures.rsa,
                    BuiltinSignatures.dsa,
                    BuiltinSignatures.nistp256,
                    BuiltinSignatures.nistp384,
                    BuiltinSignatures.nistp521,
                    BuiltinSignatures.ed25519));

            List<KeyExchangeFactory> keyExchangeFactories = new ArrayList<KeyExchangeFactory>();

            keyExchangeFactories.addAll(NamedFactory.setUpTransformedFactories(
                    false,
                    List.of(BuiltinDHFactories.curve25519),
                    ClientBuilder.DH2KEX));

            // Update the key exchange factories
            client.setKeyExchangeFactories(keyExchangeFactories);            
            // Start the client (if not already started
            client.start();

Following are the dependencies added additional to existing ones.
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.i2p.crypto</groupId>
            <artifactId>eddsa</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.70</version>
        </dependency>

